# で used to indicate the state of something

Tags: grammar

I came across this usage of で in [this](https://japaneseparticlesmaster.xyz/de-in-japanese/) article.

> 彼はお酒を熱燗で飲む 
> He drinks sake in a hot state.

Is this で the て form of the copula or the particle で?

- If its the て form of the copula, why is を and not が? What is being coupled? Is it grammatical to basically have the main clause chopped in the middle?
- If it's the particle で, how could it be that this 熱燗で tells something about the object as opposed to telling something about the verb (i.e. the "limit" within which it applies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the particle で, definition #4 of 格助詞「で」 in 明鏡国語辞典:

> で
> 〘格助〙
> ❹ 動作を行うときの**様態**を表す。
> 「急ぎ足**で**歩く」
> 「親子**で**出席する」
> 「笑顔**で**答える」
> 「土足**で**上がる」

It expresses [様態]{ようたい}, in what manner some action is performed.

It's not the copula だ→で since the sentence cannot be split to ～～熱燗だ+飲む.

---

> how could it be that this 熱燗で tells something about the object as opposed to telling something about the verb

I see it as more like 熱燗で飲む (how you drink it)...

「ポン酢**で**いただきます」「[生]{なま}**で**食べる」などの「で」だと思います。「お肉を低温**で**調理する」「ビデオを２倍速**で**再生する」なども同じ「で」だと思いますがどうでしょう。